# Solutions to fix comparison between signed and unsigned warning

Tags: c, gcc, casting, warnings, type-conversion

I'm looking for solution in the C programming language to remove this warning:

> Comparison between signed and unsigned warning

Instead of just do a `cast` to `unsigned` in the variable of `int` type, I thought as the following:

```
#if MAX_NAME >= INT_MAX
  size_t name_size = 0;
#define INT_TYPE size_t
#else
  int name_size = 0;
  #define INT_TYPE int
#endif
```

and then:

```
if(.. && name_size++ >= (INT_TYPE)sizeof(name)) {
//..
}
```

How do you fix it?

also, suggestions to name of macro `INT_TYPE` are apprecited too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is flawed: however you put it you should always use `size_t` when comparing against the result of `sizeof`. I.e. there's no reason to make `name_size` into an `int`.

As a general note, just use the "natural" signedness for that variable. It boils down to one question: is `name_size` supposed to ever be negative ?